# Jasmine error:Test fails though logic implemented to satisfy the condition

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing an angular test that compares the length of two string arrays based on a condition. I am getting error:

> Error: Expected 0 to equal 6 even though i am meeting the condition.

If you see in my test code I am initializing the idDocument object.

I am trying to test this code

```
acceptedFileTypes = this.idDocument === undefined ? [] : AcceptedFileTypes;
```

**TestComponent**

```
describe('IdUploadComponent', () => {
  let component: IdUploadComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<IdUploadComponent>;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let messageService: MessageService;
  let messageServiceSpy: jasmine.Spy;
   const event = { file: {name : 'Test'} };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [IbaModule, NgxsModule.forRoot([]), HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: AppConfigService, useClass: MockAppConfigService },
        { provide: MessageService, useClass: MockMessageService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    injector = getTestBed();
    messageService = injector.get(MessageService);
    messageServiceSpy = spyOn(messageService, 'add').and.callThrough();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IdUploadComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.fileUpload = () => undefined;
    component.idDocument = new IdDocument();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });



  it('calls messageService on upload success', () => {
    component.fileUploaded(event);

    expect(messageServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  fit('sets the fileupload to be able to upload specific files types', () => {
   const expectedResult = [ '.pdf','.heic','.jpeg','.jpg','.png','.webp'];

   component.idDocument = new IdDocument({birthCountry: 23, hasDocument: true, birthCountryRequired: true, issuedCountry: 23, required: true, uploaded: true});
   fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.acceptedFileTypes.length).toEqual(expectedResult.length);
  });
});
```

**Component**

```
export class IdUploadComponent implements OnInit {

  value: any[] = [];
  uploadUrl: string;
  componentReady = false;
  public uploading: boolean;

  @Input() documentType = '';
  @Input() section: string;
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() userId: string;
  @Input() idDocument: IdDocument;
  @Output() fileUploadEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Input() fileUpload: Function = noop;

  authHeader = {
    authorization: undefined,
    document: undefined
  };
  acceptedFileTypes = this.idDocument === undefined ? [] : AcceptedFileTypes;
  accept =  this.idDocument === undefined ? '' : AcceptedFileTypes.join(',');

  readonly maxFileSize = 10485760;

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private appConfigService: AppConfigService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authHeader.document = this.documentType;
    this.uploadUrl = this.appConfigService.appSettings.apiServer.identification + this.section
                                                                                  + '/'
                                                                                  + this.userId
                                                                                  + '/UploadIdentification';
    this.authenticationService.getAuthenticationToken().then(r => {
      this.authHeader.authorization = 'Bearer ' + r;
      this.componentReady = true;
    });


  }

}
```

Could somebody tell me what the problem is??

Answer (score 0):

In the second `beforeEach`, you set `component.idDocument = new IdDocument();` thereby it is not `undefined`, this is good. But when this component is getting created, for the line `acceptedFileTypes = this.idDocument === undefined ? [] : AcceptedFileTypes;`, I believe `this.idDocument` is undefined at this point in time. The `@Input()` values get populated in the `ngOnInit`. Even if you do `console.log(this.idDocument)` in the constructor, you will get undefined.

So to fix this, try doing the following in your component:

```
 acceptedFileTypes: any; // You can put the type here as you wish
 accept: any; // You can put the types here as you wish

 ngOnInit() {
  this.acceptedFileTypes = this.idDocument === undefined ? [] : AcceptedFileTypes;
  this.accept = this.idDocument === undefined ? ''
 : AcceptedFileTypes.join(',');
 }
```

Also, in your test that has `fit`, you are changing `component.idDocument` in the test itself. This is too late (`this.acceptedFileTypes = ...` binding in the `ngOnInit` will not update), the correct place to initialize `@Input()` is in the 2nd `beforeEach` like you have.

If you want to react to changes of `@Input()`, checkout the lifecycle hook of `ngOnChanges()`.

================= Edit =============
To test the undefined condition, unfortunately, you would have to do something like this.

```
describe('IdUploadComponent', () => {
  //.... same thing as before, initialize and compile your component
  beforeEach(async(() => )

  describe('idDocument defined', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IdUploadComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component.fileUpload = () => undefined;
      component.idDocument = new IdDocument();
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
    // your it tests with idDocument being defined can go here
 });
  describe('idDocument undefined', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IdUploadComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component.fileUpload = () => undefined;
      component.idDocument = undefined;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
    // your it tests where idDocument is undefined can go here.
  });
});
```

Comment: How do I test the === undefined condition then ?

Comment: I tried to add another before each to set it to undefined but that fails the other test

Comment: I updated my answer with regards to testing the undefined scenario.